# print another page from the current page rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, iframe

`<% @service_requests.each do |sr|%>`

`<iframe src="<%= url_for :controller=>'service_requests',:action=>'show',:id=>sr.id%>" name="frame" style="display:none;" ></iframe>`

`<input type="button" onclick="frames['frame'].print()" value="printletter">`

`<%end%>`

I want to print the show page from index page.Through this code i am able to print the show page but my concern is with **id**.Now i am getting two records having id=17 and id=15.When i am printing record with id=17,it's working fine.But if i want to print record with id 15 then i am getting the show page with id 17.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is partial views. You could render the show page with your id like this;

```
<%= render :partial => "service_requests", :locals => {:id => sr.id} %>
```